# Is it possible to conditionally close an html tag with angular 2?

Tags: html, angular

I need something like this:

```html
<tr>
  somecode...
</tr *ngIf="some condition">
```

which of course isn't supported, but is there any way to achieve this behavior?

I have a table, and I want to add rows to it recursively using a component that receives node's list(List), iterates over the nodes, print them and calls itself for each of the children of each node roughly like this:

main.component.html

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>node names</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr app-rower [nodes]="nodes"></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

rower.component.html:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let node of tree">
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{node.name}}
        </td>
    </tr *ngIf="node.hasChildren">
    <tr *ngIf="node.hasChildren" app-rower [tree]="node.children" >
    </tr *ngIf="!node.hasChildren">
</ng-container>
```

so a final html would be:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>node's names</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>node 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>node 1's child</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>node 1's grandchild</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>node 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>node 2's child</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It's not (see my answer) If you can provide more information, suggestions about how to work around might be possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's not supported. A template needs to be valid HTML otherwise Angular won't parse it.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let node of tree">
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{node.name}}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngIf="node.hasChildren" app-rower [tree]="node.children" >
    </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I edited my post to make it more clear as to what I'm trying to achieve. basically I'm trying to produce a proper table using a list of nodes

Comment: I tried to understand your example. Not sure if I succeeded. Can you please have a look and try to explain if this does what you want or how it produces a different result than the desired one?

Comment: This will not work, since you'll end up with <tr> element(from rower.component.html) inside a <tr> element(from main.component.html), therefore it will not be a legal table and will not show properly.

Comment: Hard to tell for me because I don't know what rower.component is doing. Can you please post how the HTML should look like that you want to get as result?

Comment: So app-rower is generating `<tr>`s a well and you want them all at the same level? I guess you need to flatten the data structure and then run `*ngFor` over the flat structure

Comment: If they're not at the same level the table doesn't appear properly.. So I prefer to avoid flattening it and that's why I asked about ways to get conditional closing

Comment: Right, they need to be at the same level, otherwise this results in invalid HTML. Another way might be to not use `<app-rower>` component to render the child nodes but `<template #myTemplate><ng-container *ngFor="...">
 ... </ng-container></template>` with `<template [ngTemplateOutlet]="myTemplate">`. This way you should be able to resolve recursion without flattening the data structure. You can use `ngTemplateOutlet` and `ngForTemplate` for that.